# How to install jbake from unstable with overlay in home-manager

Tags: nix, nixos

After adding the unstable channel

```
nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable unstable
```

I added an overlay under ~/.config/nixpkgs/overlays/package-upgrades/default.nix

```
self: super:
let
  unstable = import <unstable> {};
in {
  jbake = unstable.jbake;
}
```

This overlay is added to `home.nix`

```
nixpkgs.overlays = [ (import ./overlays/package-upgrades) ];
```

When I run `home-manager switch` there is an error

```
0 + john@n1 nixpkgs $ home-manager switch
Too many heap sections: Increase MAXHINCR or MAX_HEAP_SECTS
```

The entire configuration can be found [here](https://github.com/moaxcp/nix-home).

How can I upgrade a single attribute from unstable using home-manager and an overlay?

Comment: I don't think you need to explicitly add the overlay in home.nix.

Comment: I agree but I think it also overrides the default of looking in .config/nixpkgs/overlays. So I can have all the overlays in the dir and specify which ones I want to use.

Comment: I removed the line from home.nix and package-upgrades is the only overlay in use. I still get the same error.

Comment: I don't think home-manager has much of a representation in SO at this moment. You may be better off posting an issue with that project.

Comment: The underlying issue _might_ be the same as for https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/43015

Answer (score 1):

This [thread on nixos discourse](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/nix-env-i-runs-out-of-memory-with-unstable-overlay/1517) seems relevant. It appears the overlay also gets applied when importing unstable, resulting in an infinite recursion. Try something like:

```
let
  unstable = import <unstable> {};
in {
  home.packages = with pkgs; [
    ...
  ] ++ (with unstable; [
    jbake
  ]);
}
```